# ionic 4 ion-content background-image not showing on device

Tags: ionic4

I'm trying to add a background image in my ion-content
here is my current code:

```css
ion-content{
    --background: none;
    background-image: url('/assets/images/home-background.png');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I also tried the following but same thing happened.

```css
ion-content{
    --background: url('/assets/images/home-background.png')  no-repeat center center / cover;
    text-align: center;
}
```

It is working in browser but when I'm doing `ionic cordova run android`, the background image is not showing. I also tried to change the url to `url('../assets/images/home-background.png')`, `url('./assets/images/home-background.png')` and `url('../images/home-background.png')` but it's giving me error.

[I tried to check it and debug it and maybe this can help, I clicked the url and it brings me to the resources which shows me the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeMC7.png)

[In this second image, I saw the home-background.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98ISh.png)

Comment: the codes i tried working perfectly fine in browser, but when i'm trying to ionic cordova run android, the background image is not showing.

Comment: I even tried doing this --ion-background-color:#f04141;, no error but still the background of my ion-content is white when it comes to android device but working in browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

didn't have the chance to solve this problem using the ionic-content, so what I did is to change the ionic-content to div, and it solve my problem. Working in web and android device.

Comment: hi @Constantine Awa-ao

Can you help me to solve it? you can share for me? thanks

Comment: hi @thanhdung0312, sorry for the late response, I'm afraid this will not help you but what I did is I replaced the ionic-content with div and i gave that div an id which is #content_container, and on the scss file, i did a typical 
#content_container{
    background-image: url("myijmage.png");
}

Answer (score 0):

Open scss file:

```
ion-content {
    background: url('../../assets/img/myBg.jpg') center bottom no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, may I know which part will solve the problem? is it the background size setting to 100%?

Comment: not only 100% but also no-repeat bottom. it working fine for me.

Comment: I tried, but still not showing. I tried to debug the app in my android device in my browser, it doesn't give any error, but the image is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the path keep images in main www/assets/img folder and then set

```
background-image: url('assets/img/home-background.png');
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, it takes time to build the app to my android device, and still it's not working. i tried to copy the image in the  www/assets/img and try the code and it's giving me error Can't resolve 'assets/img/home-background.png'

Answer (score 0):

background-image: url('..assets/img/home-background.png');

if u have set path just type ../ or ./ automatically path will suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change your image url as shown below

```
ion-content{
--background: none;
background-image: url('../../assets/images/home-background.png');
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
text-align: center;
}
```

this worked for me.